# How to specify dynamically the 'To:' field into a SendObject within a Macro in MS Access 2003?

Tags: ms-access, macros

I'm using a form where I have one control/textbox which get populated from a query. I also have a button which launches a Macro, sending an email with an attached file.

My problem is that I want to set the value of the "To:" field within the SendObject with the value which is in the textbox in my form.

See enclosed the screenshot: http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?c6ba7d4279.jpg

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use Forms! not Form! So

```
=Forms![Reporting Trade List]!Email
```

Comment: Oops, missed the equals sign, sorry.